# java: reading elements in the same line separately

Tags: java, filereader

i know this is basic but somehow i have been stuck here for some time. if i have to read from a text file some pattern like this

```
10     9    20    12    14      29
11     3    16    30    33      26
12    20    10    14     8
```

i want all of these numbers to be takes differently. what is the basic java function that needs to be used. i did try using trim and then split but i m not getting proper result passing "|\t" as the parameter to split. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
String[] line = s.split("\\s+");
for (String next : line) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(next);
    ...
}
```

Comment: it worked. can you just tell me what the parameter \\s+ stands for? thank you.

Comment: \\s+ - a regular expressions, means any empty char (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)  symbol sequence of length one or more. See the reference guide: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 2):

The easiest to use is [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("foo.txt"));
while (sc.hasNextLong()) {
    long aLong = sc.nextLong();
}
```